# leak of the memory while using pthread_cancel()

Tags: c, thread-safety, pthreads

hello everyone I have some question about threads if for example I have some thread `1` which allocates some piece of the memory, and anohter thread (let's assume `2`) is killing thread `1` using pthread_cancel() or just using `return` what is going on with the peace of memory which it allocated? will be leak if thread `1` didn't free this piece of memory? thanks in advance for any answer

#### edited

just to make it clearer, as I know `pthread_cancel()` kills thread, but what is going on with its memory when I kill it? In case of `return` all thread will be dead if `1` is the main thread

Comment: What does "its memory" mean? Memory allocated by `malloc` does not "belong to" a thread; it belongs to the whole process. The thread's stack, on the other hand, is conceptually freed when it's cancelled, but depending on the implementation it might not be available for immediate reuse.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, it will leak memory in that case.  C does not have any garbage collection -- if you allocate memory and fail to free it, it will be leaked, plain and simple.

If you want to avoid leaking memory, don't call `pthread_cancel`.  Make your threads exit gracefully by setting a flag asking them to exit, and then when they detect that that flag is set, they can free their memory and kill themselves by returning from their thread procedures or by calling `pthread_exit`.

Alternatively, you can set a thread cleanup handler by calling [`pthread_cleanup_push`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/pthread_cleanup_pop.html), which will get called when your thread exits or gets canceled by a call to `pthread_cancel`.  You can use a handler function which will free any allocated memory you have outstanding.

Comment: Basically cancellation is impossible to use without cancellation cleanup handlers, except when the task the thread is performing involves no resource allocation whatsoever. Avoiding `phtread_cancel` is not really a good solution if the thread might be blocked on a syscall that will take a long time to return (or worse yet, which might never return), though there are ways to achieve the same thing with signals and `EINTR`...

Answer (score 2):

First of all whether it gets cancelled immediately or not depends on cancellation state.
please check "pthread_setcancelstate" and "pthread_setcanceltype".
Also it is important to have a handler after a thread is cancelled.In the handler all the resources must be freed, like locks and memory, it is similar with the return.So, Yes, there is a chance of leak if implementation is not right.
I suggest to look at the implementation of a method or function before using it.
Hope this helps.